# how to add 2 animation into 1 keyframe

Tags: css, animation

I want to add `transform : rotateY(180deg)` to the chicken after the image reach half of the animation... so in other case... i would like to create a simple walk around chicken who turn around after half animation and at the end of animation... it will turn around again and looping. (just like a people who's thinking, so they will be walk around)

can anyone help me? 
here's my sample code : http://jsfiddle.net/a7eCn/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just forgot to include the prefixes and the constant transforms (so it's not always rotating).  Here's my copy of the unprefixed -  http://jsfiddle.net/a7eCn/5/

```
@keyframes left-right {
  0% {left:140px; transform:rotateY(0);}
  50% {left:110px; transform:rotateY(0);}
  51% {transform:rotateY(180deg);}
  100% {left:140px; transform:rotateY(180deg);}
}
```

Maybe look into using [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) so you don't have to worry about prefixes at all.